# Facebook Unity SDK has error when send request with custom friends in Unity Webplayer

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

On Unity Webplayer Build, I found this error log when I call request dialog.
This problem's not appear in iOS. Anyone seen this problem?

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object
>
> Facebook.AsyncRequestDialog.InjectSecretParams
>   (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 formData)
>   Facebook.AsyncRequestDialog.Request[AsyncRequestDirectRequestPost]
>   (System.String endpoint, Facebook.HttpMethod method,
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 formData, Facebook.APIDelegate
>   callback, Facebook.ErrorDelegate errorCallback)
>   Facebook.AsyncRequestDialogPost.Post[AsyncRequestDirectRequestPost]
>   (System.String endpoint, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2
>   paramsDict, Facebook.APIDelegate callback, Facebook.ErrorDelegate
>   errorCallback) Facebook.AsyncRequestDirectRequestPost.Post
>   (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 formData,
>   Facebook.APIDelegate callback, Facebook.ErrorDelegate errorCallback)
>   Facebook.AsyncRequestDirectRequestGet.ShowDialog (System.String
>   wwwResponse) Facebook.AsyncRequestString+c__Iterator0.MoveNext
>   ()
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object  at
>   Facebook.FriendSelectorDialog+FriendList.SetCustomFilters
>   (System.String json) [0x00000] in :0   at
>   Facebook.FriendSelectorDialog.OnInit () [0x00000] in :0   at Facebook.FbSkinnedDialog.Init () [0x00000] in
>   :0   at
>   Facebook.NativeDialog.ShowDialog[FriendSelectorDialog]
>   (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 paramsDict,
>   Facebook.APIDelegate cal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the Facebook software engineers here.  Are you passing in null to the data or title param for `FB.AppRequest()`?  There's a bug where it doesn't handle that correctly currently.  Either exclude that or pass in an empty string.  We'll get that fix ASAP.

Thanks for finding that.

Update: The latest SDK version has that fix.

Comment: still this issue exists...!! i just downloaded the latest version 5.1 (FacebookSDK-140401.unitypackage) and this is disturbing.
If i remove null from the Fb.AppRequest() then AppRequest parameters give errors of not getting the exact match.
Any further help???